# Get item in array according to the value of a key within the item

Tags: php

Suppose I have an array like this:

```
$myArray = [
    [ 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'Some Name' ],
    [ 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'Some Other Name ] 
]
```

Now if want to get the second item without using the index (`$myArray[1]`), but instead by using the value of `name` which is `Some Other Name`, how do I do that?

I don't want to loop through the entire array just for one value, so how can I write this in a way that I don't explicitly loop through the array myself? I looked into `array_search()`, but couldn't find examples where `$myArray` contains additional arrays as items.

Comment: You can’t do that with `array_search` alone, that will only compare the complete items. You can use f.e. `array_filter` to filter out all elements that do not match. Or you get only the name values first, using `array_column`, then you search your name in that using `array_search` again, and then use the found key to access the item in the original array …

Comment: `array_search` uses loop too, shock!

Comment: @u_mulder The point is that I can't write a loop as it won't go through code review then. But thanks for mentioning it, really helped.

Comment: The person who does codereview is not very smart?

Comment: @u_mulder That is another factor that weighs a bit heavily as well tbh :P But no, it's a huge codebase with many rules and conventions and it's a long story to try to explain now, but I understand the question was a bit vague with the whole looping story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use *array_filter()* function:

```
<?php

$myArray = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Some Name'],
    [
        'id' => 2, 'name' => 'Some Other Name'
    ]
];


$filterData = array_filter($myArray, function ($data) {
    return $data['name'] == "Some Other Name";
});
var_dump($filterData);
die;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but you can index the array on `name`:

```
echo array_column($myArray, null, 'name')['Some Other Name']['id'];  //echos 2
```

To do it once and have access to all `name`:

```
$result = array_column($myArray, null, 'name');

echo $result['Some Other Name']['id'];  // echos 2
echo $result['Some Name']['id'];        // echos 1
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the simpliest solution:

```
$requiredItem = null;
foreach ($myArray as $item) {
    if ($item['name'] === 'Some Other Name') {
        $requiredItem = $item;
        // `break` allows you to STOP iterating over array
        break;
    }
}
print_r($requiredItem);
```

All other solutions will include **full loop** over your array at least once.